# copy, count and order all the words of a specific column and move them to other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to achieve is to copy the unique words (they repeat a few times) of sheet "Data" column A (ignoring header) to sheet "Country" column A and then add a second column to this sheet with the counting of occurrences of every word found. At same time ordering the list from higher to smaller. See the prints below as example.

Sheet "Data":

[image]

Sheet "Country" and the output i want to accomplish:

[image]

What I have so far, but not working (givin' error):

```
Sub Count_Sort()
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim ws As String
Dim c As Range

ws = ActiveSheet.Name
lastRow = LastUsedRow
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
ActiveSheet.Name = "Country"
Sheets(ws).Activate
Set c = Range("A1")
Set d = Sheets("Country").Range("A1")
Do While Not IsEmpty(c)
    Do While Not IsEmpty(d)

        If c.Value = d.Value Then

            d.Offset(0, 1).Value = d.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
            Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)
            Exit Do
        End If
        Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    Set c = c.Offset(1, 0)
    Set d = Sheets("Country").Range("A1")
Loop
End Sub


Public Function LastUsedRow()
LastUsedRow = [A65536].End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Any help would be most welcome...

Ps. I intend to do the same to all the columns of sheet "Data" (around 20), copy to a different sheet and then count and order each word. But if i manage to this in one, i think i will get to the others. Thanks again.

Comment: what error and what line of code?

Comment: run time error1004 - application defined or object defined error

Comment: I think my problem is: which code should I change to make the code run on a specific sheet called "data" and the data starts on B2, not A1.. Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: please see my answer. I modified your code significantly, but I think it's for the better and will be easy to understand, read and or edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the general structure of your code:

```
Sub Count_Sort()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet, cs As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Data")
ws.Select

ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select     'Update for different data column
Selection.Copy

Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Country"               'Update for different data column
Set cs = Sheets("Country")                 'Update for different data column

cs.Range("A2").Select
cs.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
cs.Range("A2", cs.Range("A2").End(xlDown)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
cs.Range("A1") = ws.Range("A1").Value          'Update for different data column (only ws.Range("A1").Value) (this is just the column heading)
cs.Range("B1") = "X times"

For i = 1 To cs.Range("A2", cs.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count         
    cs.Cells(1 + i, 2) = Application.CountIf(ws.Range("A2", ws.Range("A2").End(xlDown)), cs.Cells(1 + i, 1))          'Update for different data column
Next i

cs.Range(cs.Cells(2, 1), cs.Cells(cs.Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row, 2)).Sort Key1:=cs.Range("B1"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

You can then just change the references for the different columns and/or worksheets.

Additionally, you should consider adding some error handling or checks to make sure your code doesn't crash if the sheet you are adding exists.

Comment: its seems be working good:) one question: if the input starts in cell c2 instead of A2 for instance, which code do I need to update? thanks a lot

Comment: I have marked on the code the locations that would need to be updated. These will simply be changing the A to C or whatever column the source data is in. Accept the answer if this has worked :) Thanks

Comment: gives an error: Run-time error 6. Overflow. It copies the unique values to new sheet, gives header correct, but then doesnt count the occurrences.

Comment: I apologise, I told you to update one line too many. You do not need to modify the line containing the For Loop, and only need to modify the second occurrence of "A" in the line cs.Range("A1") = ws.Range("A1").Value . I have tested this now, and it seems to work for me. I have also amended my answer to take into account this comment.

Comment: not a problem. actually now it has different error: run time error1004 - application defined or object defined error. I think I know the problem. Your code doesnt work it the data in column be all the same. For example: es es es es. In such case it gets error.

Comment: I think the issue (if I recreated the same one) is to do with selecting the data. I'm not overly familiar with how .Select works, but I suspect that you are getting the problem when trying to run the code when not on the Data sheet? I managed to fix it by adding ws.Select below the Set ws = Sheets("Data")

Comment: You are right, so far i blieve that is 1 of 2 issue. The other is that if the column just have the same data in all rows.

Comment: I never thought of that. Quite a specific occurrence. Change the For loop to the following For i = 1 To cs.Range("A2", cs.Range("A2").End(xlDown).End(xlUp)).Rows.Count

Comment: You helped a lot. One last question :) Other error i found is that if the column has an empty cell, it gets error. Any idea how to avoid it? To ignore empty cells.

Comment: I think the problem is the .End(xlDown) statement which stops when it gets to a blank cell downwards. I think you need to update your code to use your lastRow function that you included in your question, instead of xlDown

Comment: do you mind update your code to help me have a clear idea? thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do without any VBA at all, using excel's built-in functions and techniques. However, since it seems you have many to do, I would like to suggest using VBA to utilize Excels existing tools to help you do the work faster (and with less code):

Also, it's best practice to avoid using `.Select` and `.Active` statements as much as possible.

```
Sub Count_Sort()

Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsA As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Data") 'ActiveSheet.Name ... better to use actual sheet name
Set wsA = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))

With ws

    lastRow = LastUsedRow
    .Range("B2:A" & lastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=wsA.Range("A1"), Unique:=True

End With

With wsA

    .Name = "Country"

    With .Range("B2")
        .Formula = "=Countif(" & ws.Name & "!A:A,A2)"
        .AutoFill wsA.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(, 1)
    End With

End With

End Sub

Public Function LastUsedRow()
LastUsedRow = [A65536].End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Comment: it gets an error: object require in : Set ws = Sheets("Data")

Comment: do you have a sheet called `Data` as you stated? If not, change the name to the name of the sheet where your data resides.

Comment: so sorry, I dim the worksheets as string, instead of worksheet. I fixed it. Try now.